# Use GameKit without GameCenter

Tags: ios, xcode5, gamekit

We're using GameKit; it's an API for sending and receiving bluetooth and wifi messages.

Xcode5 keeps turning on "GameCenter" (which we're not using, and will never use - this isn't a game!), generating errors in the Xcode project. If I turn it off, and go to a different file, then come back ... Xcode5 turns it on again.

I know Apple's docs are badly wrong (someone who didn't know what GK was ... did a bad copy/paste job from the old GK and GC docs, merged them into one, which is wrong), but they're very obviously separate tech and code. Is there a way to prevent Xcode5 from falsely enabling GC?